# "FCM" App Crashes on this line getToken() "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process"

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, android-developer-api

## FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) initialize issue

I started working on FCM module, I fallowed as per the firebase guidelines. i'm getting two exceptions like RuntimeException and IllegalStateException. Firebase init default but why and what is the issue in FCM.

#### 1. From Android Studio tools -> Firebase -> Cloud Messaging.

#### 2. I fallowed Set up Firebase Cloud Mesasging.

I fallowed below link:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

App : Build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.4.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Project : Build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

In MainActivity.class, i trying to get token but app crashes.

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String tokenId = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken(); //Crashes in this line 
        Log.d("SH", tokenId);
    }
}
```

in logcat i got two exceptions

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.package PID: 29368
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.package.testfcm/com.package.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.package. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2861)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2943)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1630)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6626)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.package. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:240)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance(Unknown Source:1)
        at com.package.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7032)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7023)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1236)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2814)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2943) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1630) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6626) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
```

Finally i found solutions, Now i able to get FCM Token.

#### In project build.gradle file you need add single line code code i.e., mavenLocal().

Fallow as per the below solutions cross check the project : build.gradle file and app : build.gradle file.

Project : build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()  //This is the line you need to add 
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal() //This is the line you need to add 
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

App : build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.testfcm"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'


    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.5.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Make sure you have added google json file in your app and check package name in the file with your package name. and finally add FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this); in activity

Comment: Yes i added google json file.

Comment: Firebase needs time to connect to it server and gives you the instance referred to your device , give it some time or use a promise to make sure firebase is connected to it server and instance is generated, then perform the action that need firebase instance.

Comment: Finally i found a solutions. Just you need to add single line code in project build.gradle file i.e., mavenLocal();

Answer (score 0):

I can see from your code that you are getting Firebase instance before it had to be initialized. You have to first initialize it then get token using `getInstance()`.

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
```

Or try the way google documents shows for getting token

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "getInstanceId failed", task.getException());
                    return;
                }

                // Get new Instance ID token
                String token = task.getResult().getToken();


                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, token, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Check updated answer

Comment: Yes i checked above answer still getting same  exceptions and same crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

In Android Studio GO TO TOOLS Menu.

Then Select Firebase Option.

Provide your firebase enabled google account id-password.

From right side tab select Cloud Messaging.

Then click on setup firebase messaging .

Follow mension steps over there.